# friend injection fails on all compilers except MSVC

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, friend

Consider the below code.

```
struct foo {
  friend foo create(foo) { return {}; }
};

int main() {

  auto a = create(foo{});

  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles perfectly on all compilers.

But the next below code compiles only in MSVC.

```
struct foo {};

struct bar {
  friend bar create(foo) { return {}; }
};

int main() {

  auto a = create(foo{});

  return 0;
}
```

Other compilers, such as gcc, clang fail to compile with the following error.

```
error: 'create' was not declared in this scope
   9 |   auto a = create(foo{});
```

Is this non-standard?

I'm working on some template thing, so I must declare the friend function inside of the `bar`.
Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Define it outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within a class or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers X) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided - see namespaces for details.

Visual studio is not complying with the standard here, your first version works as the use of `foo` triggers ADL.

One option is to also declare the function outside the class:

```
struct foo {};

struct bar {
  friend bar create(foo) { return {}; }
};

bar create(foo);

int main() {

  auto a = create(foo{});

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with declaring in `foo` with return type `auto`.
It only works in C++ >= 14, but compiled in gcc >= 6.0, clang >= 8.0.

```
struct foo {
  friend auto create(foo);
};

struct bar {
  friend auto create(foo) { return bar{}; }
};

int main() {

  auto a = create(foo{});

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need of `auto` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nzKEvWxxe). you added a `friend` declaration in `foo` which is found by ADL (and defined in `bar`).